# Training the datasets in R studio

Tags: r, nan, training-data

I am dividing the datasets into 70% of the training and 30% as validating set. There are lots of NaN variables too and maybe because of that, I could not train my data. Although, I was able to differentiate the datasets into training and test datasets. but when I want to train, I am getting this error ("Error in na.fail.default(list(ndvi = c(0.426755102040816, 0.409, 0.501735849056604, : missing values in object").

I want to estimate biomass using NDVI and then see the relationship with the observed biomass.

```r
set.seed(123)
inTrain = createDataPartition(newdata$ndvi, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
training = newdata[ inTrain,]
testing = newdata[-inTrain,]
cols <- c("ndvi", "first", "second", "third","DMY_kg_ha")
newdata[cols] <- lapply(newdata[cols], factor)  ## as.factor() could also be used
set.seed(32343)
modelFit<-train(DMY_kg_ha~first+second+third+treatment, data=training, method='glm',na.rm = na.omit)
modelFit
```

After creating modelfit, I want to use 'vif' in R to find out which variables are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
# load library
library(caret)

# set seed value
set.seed(123)

# remove NA's in data
newdata = na.omit(newdata)

# split data set
inTrain = createDataPartition(newdata$ndvi, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
training = newdata[ inTrain,]
testing = newdata[-inTrain,]

# convert columns to factors
cols <- c("ndvi", "first", "second", "third","DMY_kg_ha")
newdata[cols] <- lapply(newdata[cols], factor)  ## as.factor() could also be used

# reset seed value
set.seed(32343)

# train model
modelFit<-train(DMY_kg_ha~first+second+third+treatment, data=training, method='glm',na.rm = na.omit)

# view model
modelFit
```

Comment: Thank you so much but still I am having issue with "Some classes have a single record " and I was not able to train the model yet.

Comment: In that case use `mice` package for imputing NA's. This documentation should help you on how to's https://github.com/nagdevAmruthnath/Predictive-Maintenance/blob/master/Predictive%20Maintenance%20-%20Data%20Imputation.ipynb

Comment: Thank you @Not_Dave. Hope this will be me to solve the issue.